# QOpenGLWidget blocks all threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

There are two threads. One thread for OpenGL. Function paintGL() calls update(). Its performance is 60 fps because of OpenGL limits. When paintGL ends the next paintGL starts in 16 sec. 
The second thread sends and recieves data to/from server more often than 60 fps (aproximately 500 times per sec.) And the problem is: 
After paintGL ends the second thread stops. 
Application output looks like this:

```
Net::process() "23:01:23.193 "
Net::process() "23:01:23.193 "
paintGL start  "23:01:23.193 "
Net::process() "23:01:23.193 "
Net::process() "23:01:23.193 "
paintGL ok  "23:01:23.193 "
Net::process() "23:01:23.193 "
Net::process() "23:01:23.209 "
Net::process() "23:01:23.209 "
```

Why there is Net::process() "23:01:23.209 " after Net::process() "23:01:23.193 " when it belongs to the second thread?

```
void MyGL::paintGL()
{
qDebug()<<"paintGL start "<< QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz ");
if(isInit==false)init();

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

programImage.setUniformValue("mvp_matrix", matrixBase);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

update();
qDebug()<<"paintGL ok "<< QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz ");
}
```

//////////net////////////////

```
MyNet::MyNet(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
QThread* thread = new QThread;

this->moveToThread(thread);
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(process()));


connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

thread->start();

}

void MyNet::process()
{
//send and recieve data 
qDebug()<<"Net::process()"<< QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz ");

QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(process()));
}
```

Comment: Maybe the OS preempted that worker thread for a little bit given it was running constantly?

Comment: @peppe , it always happens after the function paintGL()

Comment: What does a profiler say?

Comment: It's not 16 sec, it's rather 16 **milli-seconds**, which is very likely the resolution of your system clock (i.e. it increments in jumps).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with the help of ybungalobill and his comment

> the resolution of your system clock (i.e. it increments in jumps)
>   Thanks.